# Is there some shortcut for calling this.Invoke every time a callback needs to access the UI? Some automatic delegation to the UI thread?

Tags: wpf, winforms, user-interface, c#-4.0, invoke

I'm developing a Windows Forms GUI in [a design pattern which is a combination of MVP and MVVM](http://aviadezra.blogspot.com/2009/08/mvp-mvvm-winforms-data-binding.html).*

I'm binding the View to the View Model using code: the view subscribes to the VM's `PropertyChanged` event. If the presenter sets some property of the VM, the event is raised and the View executes its callback.

So every callback in the View needs to be wrapped in `this.Invoke( { ... } )`.

I wish there was a way **to define a property whose setter will automatically be invoked in the UI thread.** Some way to write an **auto-delegating property or method.**

I tagged this question with WPF as well, because I'm using C# 4.0, so if such a mechanism exists in WPF, I'll be happy to use it for Windows Forms.

*I'm using MVVM because the application will probably be converted to WPF at some stage.

Comment: Can you provide some pseudo code of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @Jeff, thanks for trying to help, anyway see my answer below. But if you have any insights, I'll be happy to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suddenly realized that the IoC Framework I'm using, Castle Windsor, can give me exactly that. I just attached an interceptor to all the methods of the form, and the interceptor does this:

```
if (invocation.InvocationTarget.InvokeRequired)
{
     invocation.InvocationTarget.Invoke(invocation.Proceed);
}
else
{
     invocation.Proceed();
}
```

Later I modified the above code by putting it in an extension method with the following signature:

```
public void InvokeIfRequired(this Control uiObject, Action action)
```

Answer (score 1):

To define a property setter that always gets invoked on the UI thread, you could do something like this:

```
public int MyPropertyForTheUIThread
{
    get
    {
        return this.myRealValue;
    }

    set
    {
        if (this.myRealValue != value)
        {
            this.myRealValue = value;
            this.Invoke((Action)(()=>
                {
                    // The stuff I want to do on the UI thread when this property changes.
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It still forces me to put a lot of InvokeRequested and Invoke calls in my code, a large piece of code for every property. I thought there was something that would save me the extra code.